# Android: Toast.makeText() = java.lang.RuntimeException (Can't create handler inside Thread...)

Tags: java, android, исключения, android-toast, android-threads

Доброго времени суток. Есть проблема. За всё время программирования на Android, на своём пути я ещё, к удивлению, не встречал такую ошибку.

Есть обыкновенный `Toast`. Сообщение его находится в отдельном классе в статическом методе:

```
public class A {
    
    ...
    
    public static void e(Context i1, Exception e1) {
        Toast.makeText(i1, i1.getResources().getString(R.string.error2) + ":" + "\n" + e1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    
    ...
    
}
```

Вызывается он с совершенно разных `Activity`. Сделал я это для того, чтобы по 500 раз не писать `Toast.makeText(...)` в `try {} catch {}` блоках. Вот пример кода одной из `Activity`:

```
...
try {
    new File(...).createNewFile();
} catch (Exception e1) {
    A.e(this, e1);
}
...
```

Возможно, Вы уже где-то видите ошибку в представленных кодах. Но я нет. Помогите мне избавиться от этой Exception, которая портит всё:

> 09-12 17:50:02.693: E/AndroidRuntime(6101): Process: com.example, PID: 6101
>
> 09-12 17:50:02.693: E/AndroidRuntime(6101): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
>
> ...
>
> 09-12 17:50:02.693: E/AndroidRuntime(6101):   at com.example.A.e(I.java:26)
>
> ...

26-я строка класса `I.java` и есть строка `Toast.makeText(i1, i1.getResources()...).show();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что вы пытаетесь выполнять работу с UIв не-UI-потоке.
Если ваш код находится в Activity, то измените его так:

```
try {
    new File(...).createNewFile();
} catch (Exception e1) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
              A.e(this, e1);
         }
    });

}
```

Comment: странная вещь происходит. он мне 4 раза одну и ту же toast показал. вроде только один раз просил

Comment: @L'Esperanza, значит вы выполнили код 4 раза

Comment: за ответ спасибо. но что-то я сегодня туплю походу. try {} catch (Exception e1) { ...I.e(e1) ...} четыре раза Toast быть не может

Comment: какие-то чудеса у меня вечно с этой Jav'ой

Comment: @L'Esperanza поставьте точку останова, и в дебаге убедитесь, что код выполняется 4 раза

Comment: верно, ошибка где-то ещё. Log всё доказал. Спасибо за решение проблемы по Toast'у.